# I have 2 classes and its being put through some tests - I keep getting the error: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'student_list'

Tags: python, class

```py
class Student:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, id):
        
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.id = id

    def __str__(self):

        return "{} {}, {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name, self.id)

class Course:
    def __init__(self, course_name, student_list):

        self.course_name = course_name
        self.student_list = student_list

    def add_student(self):
        
        self.student_list.append("{}, {}, {}".format(self.first_name, self.last_name, self.id))
        
        return self.student_list
```

I've tried changing things but then I lose the correctness points I have so far and I haven't a clue what needs to be done.

The full error traceback is:

```
test_default_case (coding_rooms_unit_tests.CodingRoomsUnitTests) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_default_case (coding_rooms_unit_tests.CodingRoomsUnitTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usercode/coding_rooms_unit_tests.py", line 14, in test_default_case
    course = Course("Programming")
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'student_list'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: Please update your question with these tests you mention plus the full error traceback.

Comment: The error you just posted is telling you: You wrote `Course("Programming")` (with `"Programming"` being the `course_name` in the `Course.__init__`'s method definition). But the Course's `__init__` is also expecting a second argument `, student_list)` which you're not providing.

Comment: So why did you write the test like that? (I mean: `course = Course("Programming")`) - you only supply one parameter even though you define `class Course` as needing two. Did you really mean to not have two parameters, but instead just have the first and then have: `self.student_list = []`?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `course = Course("Programming")`, what do you expect this to mean? Where the code says `def __init__(self, course_name, student_list):`, what do you think this tells you about the `Course` class? Where the code says `self.student_list = student_list`, where do you think this value will come from, and why? What do you think the value should be, and how did the code `course = Course("Programming")` explain this?

Comment: It looks like the code `course = Course("Programming")` comes from an automated test; therefore it tells you how `Course` should be called. Therefore - perhaps you can think of a different way to write the `__init__` method? Perhaps you can think of a different way for `self.student_list` to get its value? What should its value be, and why? (Hint: **read the assignment specification**.)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you’re not setting the value for the student_list variable. In this case you should provide a list. For example:

```
course = Course(‘Programming’, [‘Alfred’, ‘Bob’, ‘Cynthia’])
```

Then these variable values are assigned to the state of the object which you can check with `course.course_name` and `course.student_list`